# Does using postMessage and fetch from the page create a race condition with ServiceWorkers?

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker

I'm new to ServiceWorkers, but I wanted to keep my homepage as fresh as possible by using the cache then network pattern as outline in [Google's offline cookbook](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/offline-cookbook#cache-then-network).

However, I am using static html instead of data streams, and the source code linked to Google's documentation does not use the example. So I came up with a pattern that works in testing, but I'm concerned it introduces a race condition.

The pattern I am trying to achieve is:

1. Request
2. ServiceWorker returns cached response
3. Page posts message to ServiceWorker, telling it to use the network on the next load
4. Page makes `fetch` request
5. ServiceWorker updates cache and returns network response
6. Page updates with the network response

However, there may be a race condition between **3** and **4**.

The issue is that **3** and **4** happen in the client, while **5** happens in the ServiceWorker.

I am unsure of the potential delay caused by [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Client/postMessage). If it is substantial, **4** will fetch the page before the ServiceWorker is aware it should be fetching from the network, and a repeat cached response will be returned.

Is this the case? Or will the ServiceWorker always have time to update the flag from the `postMessage()` before the next fetch request is made?

## Source

**Page**

```js
let isControlled = navigator.serviceWorker.controller;
let isHomepage = location.href === location.origin + '/';
let homepageCached = getCookie('homecached') === 'true';

if (isControlled && !homepageCached) {

  // If the cookie is expired or unset, push an update to the service worker and update cookie
  navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage('updateHomepageCache');
  // `1` means store the cookie for 1 day
  setCookie('homecached', 'true', 1);

  if (isHomepage) {

    // This works easily with location.reload(), but it's sloppy and causes a flicker
    let existingMain = document.querySelector('.main');
    fetch(location.href)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.text();
    }).then(function(text) {
      try {

        // Convert response text to a new document
        let parser = new DOMParser();
        let doc = parser.parseFromString(text, 'text/html');

        // Get `main` element of response and update the current document with it
        let fetchedMain = doc.querySelector('.main');
        let parent = existingMain.parentNode;
        parent.replaceChild(fetchedMain, existingMain);

      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**Service Worker**

```js
// Set flag to false so update only happens when cache is invalid
let updateHomepageCache = false;

self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {

  // Update flag if cache is invalid
  // Note, this comes after fetch in the ServiceWorker's lifecycle
  if (event.data === 'updateHomepageCache') {
    updateHomepageCache = true;
  }
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {

  const normalizedUrl = new URL(event.request.url);
  normalizedUrl.search = '';

  const isNavgation = event.request.mode === 'navigate';
  const isFromOrigin = normalizedUrl.origin === location.origin;
  const isHomepage = normalizedUrl.href === location.origin + '/';

  // Respond with network and update cache for homepage (if it needs to be updated)
  if (isHomepage && isNavgation && updateHomepageCache) {
    event.respondWith(
      caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
        return fetch(normalizedUrl).then(function(networkResponse) {
          cache.put(normalizedUrl, networkResponse.clone());
          updateHomepageCache = false;
          return networkResponse;
        }).catch(function() {
          return cache.match(normalizedUrl);
        });
      })
    );

  // Cache then update cache with network response for pages "stale-while-revalidate"
  } else if (isFromOrigin && isNavgation) {
    event.respondWith(
      caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
        return cache.match(normalizedUrl).then(function(response) {
          let fetchPromise = fetch(normalizedUrl).then(function(networkResponse) {
            cache.put(normalizedUrl, networkResponse.clone());
            return networkResponse;
          });
          return response || fetchPromise;
        });
      })
    );
});
```

Comment: ... Both will synchronously *queue a task* to fire the event, but on different event task source... Interesting question... I'd assume postMessage would win since you called it first, but can't tell for sure. In your position I'd rather wait for confirmation from the SW before starting the fetch.

Comment: I tried posting a message to all clients back from the SW, but adding an event listener on the window didn't detect the messages... I may have done something wrong but it didn't seem like a viable approach. Otherwise I agree.

Comment: I would personally use a [MessageChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageChannel) (even though I never did with a SW). So you can do `const channel = new MessageChannel(); const resp = new Promise( res => channel.port1.onmessage = res ); sw.postMessage( 'update-cache', [ channel.port2 ] ); await resp;` and in SW `addEventListener('message', (e) => { if( e.data === "update-cache" && e.ports)  { updateCache(); e.ports[0].postMessage('done'); } })`

Comment: Amazing, that worked perfectly. Thank you so much. I added it to my code because it is comforting, but I'm going to leave this question open because I think it is an interesting condition.